# JSON deserialization class

Tags: c#, json.net

Cant figure out where i deserialized wrong?

C# JSON classes:

```
AllProjects [] AllProjectsList;

public class AllProjects
{
    public Project [] Projects { get; set; }
}
public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty("self")]
    public string self { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("avatarUrls")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Result { get; set; }
}
```

My JSON string:

```
[{
"self":"https://test.test.com/rest/api/2/project/AAAVOA",
"id":"11211",   
"key":"AAAVOA",
"name":"AAA VOA",
"avatarUrls":   
    {
        "16x16":"https://test.test.com/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=11211&avatarId=10281",
        "48x48":"https://test.test.com/secure/projectavatar?pid=11211&avatarId=10281"
    }
},
{
"self": ...
```

And deserialization code:

```
 AllProjectsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllProjects>(response.Content) as AllProjects;
```

Comment: Nor can we because you haven't told us what error you're getting :)  Please update the question to add the specific exception you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your deserialization line. You can simply do this :

```
List<Project> projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(response.Content);
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You may check [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to get an idea of what your classes should look like.

Comment: Thanks, checked myself. I forgot 1 row =)))